# How to do a IF statement in PowerBI using 2 columns from different tables?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm struggling with something that should be simple:

IF Column A in table 1 = Column B in table 2 then "No Change" else "Change"

I tried creating a new column under table 1 using this:

```
ActionItem = IF((Column A] = related(table2[ColumnB]), "No Change", "Change")
```

I do have [one to many] relationship between the tables

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this a measure or column? if a measure then you need to wrap the column references with a formula (eg. sum, count, values, etc).

If there already exists a relationship between the columns then you don't need the related().

If this is in a calculated column then it should work as long as the relationship is set up directly.

Comment: count, sum would be the wrong aggregate to use right ? now i get results but the logic is wrong in some...

Comment: I don't have the context for the formula so i don't know which aggregator to recommend to you. for example, depending on what you pivt on the rows/columns of the pivot, either a single row's value will show up in the value section (in which case, you are indfifferent to max,min,sum) or multiple rows will show up. In the case of multiple rows, you would need to decide what do you want this to do? average or sum or the most common aggregation formulas.